# Page redirects in browser but not in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to test sites to see if they redirect from a HTTP to HTTPS.  Here is my code.

```
import requests
url = "http://www.google.com"
page = requests.get(url)
if page.history:
    print ("Request was redirected")
    for resp in page.history:
        print (resp.status_code, resp.url)
    print ("Final destination:")
    print (page.status_code, page.url)
else:
    print (page.headers)
    print (page.history)
    print(page.url)
    print(page.status_code)
    print ("Request was not redirected")
```

When I test `http://www.google.com` using various online header checkers I get a 302 redirect to the https site.  However, when I run the code above I get a 200 status code and a page result.  However, when I run the code with a site like `http://fb.com` I get the following result.

```
Request was redirected
301 http://fb.com/
302 http://www.facebook.com/?_rdr
Final destination:
200 https://www.facebook.com/
```

Is this just some how a Google thing or am I missing something.

Comment: What is the page you get? Did Google block you maybe?

Comment: Works for me but try passing  a real user-agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does a lot of magic based on the user agent string. Try fetching as

```
page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})
```

or with some other user agent string and see if that changes the behaviour.

Also, be aware that if you hit Google with a script, it doesn't take long until you get blocked and see captchas at least, even if you have a real user agent string.

Comment: @Padraic Cunnigham: I know it looks like I scooped you but I didn't. I actually was trying the same thing as you were posting you comment.

Comment: Well thanks to you both.  I was using a real user agent in httplib elsewhere in my code.  Should have figured that out.